# Does MapKit support Google StreetView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mapkit

Is there anyway of displaying Google StreetView in my ipad app, or in the future are there any known plans to support it?  Is there any other way of showing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, use a link to the coordinate to open in the maps app. With the way things are going between Apple and Google it's not likely to happen anytime soon.

Here's an example:

http://maps.google.com/?q=Tokyo@35.680,139.769

Comment: This is too bad. It would be great.